# Why does using "once" instead of "on" break things here?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, checkbox

So I built an app where you enter the name of your favorite book and author in a form, and it generates a card with that information.

There's a checkbox on the form to mark if you own it and a "remove" button.

It works with an `addtoLibrary()` function that takes the info from the form, puts it into an object and that object into firebase.

Within that function, I have another function called `render()` which takes the info from firebase and puts it into the DOM.

Next I added another function called `retrievefromDatabase()` which also incorporates the `render()` function, and loops through the list of objects to draw cards for the items that exist in the database.

The problem I'm facing now is that whenever the checkbox is checked or unchecked, the `retrievefromDatabase()` function activates and draws another card.

I think if I could change the `on` in the second database call to `once` here, that would solve my problem. But when I do that, all the fields in my card render to "undefined."

I'm not sure why it's even doing that, because the initial database call is a `once` that loops over every object key, and there are no new object keys when the checkbox changes. It's just a change of state for the object.

```js
function retrievefromDatabase() {
  firebase.database().ref("Book").once("value", gotData);
      function gotData(Book) {
      var books = Book.val();
      var keys = Object.keys(books);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          firebase.database().ref("Book/" + keys[i]).on("value", function(snapshot) {
          newPostKey = snapshot.key;    
          function oldBook(title, fname, lname, pubDate, contrib, own) {
            this.title = title;
            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
            this.pubDate = pubDate;
            this.contrib = contrib;
            this.own = own;
          };          
          var archiveBook = new oldBook(snapshot.val().title, 
          snapshot.val().fname, 
          snapshot.val().lname, 
          snapshot.val().pubDate,
          snapshot.val().contrib,
          snapshot.val().own);
          render();
        })}}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a listener to a location in the database, you get a snapshot with all data under that location. This means that there is no need to attach a listener to nodes under that location in the callback.

In addition, it is much easier to loop over the child nodes of a snapshot with `snapshot.forEach()`, instead of extracting the keys and then using those.

So your code can be simplified to:

```
function retrievefromDatabase() {
    firebase.database().ref("Book").once("value", (book) => {
        book.forEach((snapshot) => {
            newPostKey = snapshot.key;

            function oldBook(title, fname, lname, pubDate, contrib, own) {
                this.title = title;
                this.fname = fname;
                this.lname = lname;
                this.pubDate = pubDate;
                this.contrib = contrib;
                this.own = own;
            };
            var archiveBook = new oldBook(snapshot.val().title,
                snapshot.val().fname,
                snapshot.val().lname,
                snapshot.val().pubDate,
                snapshot.val().contrib,
                snapshot.val().own);
        })
        render();
    }
};
```

On `on` vs `once`:

- if you only want to get the data once, you should use `once`. This also means that you'll have to call `retrievefromDatabase` each time you want to load the data.
- if you want to continue to monitor the database for changes after retrieving the data, you should use `on`. In this case, be sure to only call `retrievefromDatabase` once, as you don't want to attach multiple permanent listeners.

Comment: Thanks Frank! That was very smart, using the `.forEach()` ... I knew there had to be a way to avoid pulling from the database twice. I wound up rewriting the function to not reuse the `render()` function, which resulted in way longer code. I've attached that as an answer just for posterity.

Comment: I spoke too soon! I tried the new code, and it's doing the same thing that I mention here: "I think if I could change the on in the second database call to once here, that would solve my problem. But when I do that, all the fields in my card render to "undefined.""

Comment: There is only a single database call in my answer, and it uses once. If you have a new problem after applying the solution in my answer, I recommend opening a new question. If the code in my answer doesn't work, please show how you use it.

Comment: true, there's only one database call. Ok, let me try to see what's wrong on my own and maybe I'll have something more to post soon! thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the constructor, alas!

Comment: ok, I re-asked! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321366/why-am-i-getting-undefined-when-i-try-to-retrieve-this-array-of-objects-from-f

Answer (score 0):

This is what I attempted, which worked, but is much uglier than Frank's solution:

```
function retrievefromDatabase() {
firebase.database().ref("Book").once("value", gotData);
  function gotData(Book) {
    var books = Book.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(books);
  
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

      firebase.database().ref("Book/" + keys[i]).once("value", function(snapshot) {  
      titlesnap = snapshot.val().title; 
      fnamesnap = snapshot.val().fname;
      lnamesnap = snapshot.val().lname;
      pubsnap = snapshot.val().pubDate;
      contribsnap = snapshot.val().contrib;
      newPostKey = snapshot.key;

      const bookContainer = document.createElement("div");
      bookContainer.classList.add("book-container");
      const newVolume = document.createElement("div");
      newVolume.classList.add("volume");
      bookContainer.appendChild(newVolume);
      bookContainer.setAttribute('id', `${newPostKey}`);
      const frontCover = document.createElement("div");
      newVolume.appendChild(frontCover);
      frontCover.style.setProperty("background-color", getRandomColor());

      frontCover.innerHTML = "<br /><br />"
      + "<b>" + titlesnap + "</b>" + "<br /><br />" 
      + fnamesnap + "&nbsp;"
      + lnamesnap + "<br /><br />"
      + "Published: " + pubsnap + "<br />"
      + "Added by: <br />" + contribsnap + "<br />";

      const checkbox = document.createElement('input'); 
      checkbox.type = "checkbox"; 
      checkbox.id = "checkbox"; 
    
      if (snapshot.val().own == true) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
      }
      else {
        checkbox.checked = false;
      };  
      
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (checkbox.checked === false) {
      firebase.database().ref('Book/' + bookContainer.id + '/own').set(false);
    }
    else if (checkbox.checked === true) {
      firebase.database().ref('Book/' + bookContainer.id + '/own').set(true);
        }});

    const label = document.createElement("label"); 
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" I own a copy")); 
    const newgraf = document.createElement("p")
    
    frontCover.appendChild(checkbox);
    frontCover.appendChild(label);
    frontCover.appendChild(newgraf);
    
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button')
    frontCover.appendChild(removeButton);
    removeButton.textContent = 'Remove';
    removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        firebase.database().ref('Book/').child(bookContainer.id).remove()
        bookContainer.remove();
    })

      libraryContainer.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',bookContainer);
      });
};
  };};
```